# Bitlocker, SSD, Windows 11

Tags: ssd, bitlocker

I have a problem with bitlocker today. I needed to remove bitlocker from my ssd, that is, decrypt it, the decryption process stopped and I had nothing to do but restart my laptop, and after that the main problem appeared: BIOS and Windows do not see this ssd, even diskpart writes through the command line in the Windows recovery tools that there is no disks, thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a chance that the drive died during the process. If by gone from BIOS you mean like the SATA port page or so instead of the boot menu, then I don't know what to suggest apart from tests of hardware level (e.g. reconnecting the drive, or test the same port and cable with another drive, etc.).